# Need to get unique IDs of various storage devices (usb stick, SD card, external HDD, etc)..

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to come up with something that will let me obtain a unique ID of some sort for most types of storage devices.  These can be USB thumb drives, SD cards, external hard drives, etc.

I have run across this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But I can't find anything similar within .NET.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My end goal is to be able to define specific hardware storage devices, and then have my application auto-detect them when they are plugged in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Visit these links, you may find these helpful but these are for usb device only also I am sure that you will find your way to code for other devices. Good luck

http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/USB_SerialNumbers.htm

http://forum.codecall.net/visual-basic-tutorials/26304-detect-when-usb-w32disk-plugged.html#post244584